# ctrl+shift+tab not working correctly

Tags: 18.04, lubuntu, shortcut-keys

I just installed `lubuntu` 18.04 from scratch and I'm noticing a glitch: in both firefox and chromium `ctrl+tab` switches correctly to the next tab on the right, but `ctrl+shift+tab` works intermittently and only if I hold the buttons a little longer than usual. How can this happen?

Answer (score 1):

Recently used order setting needs to be off

> If you want to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> to switch to the tab next to the current tab and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> to switch to the previous tab, deselect this setting (clear the checkbox).

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/tab-preferences-and-settings